# How can I find out if a host is a container or a virtual machine with Ansible facts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Is there any way to find out if a host is a container or a virtual machine in gathered facts or in other methods?

Comment: Did you already look at `ansible_virtualization_type`? Detecting containerization is going to be harder, since the only thing that makes it "containerized" is linux namespace trickery; but if you have more specific interest, such as "in a kubernetes Pod" or "in a docker container" then some of the env-vars may give it away

Answer (score 1):

Just gather [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts). From a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true

  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "min"
  # - "hardware"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

the output result will already contain the requested information

```yaml
    os_family: RedHat
    product_name: VMware7,1
    system: Linux
    system_vendor: VMware, Inc.
    virtualization_role: guest
    virtualization_type: VMware
```

or

```yaml
    os_family: RedHat
    product_name: Virtual Machine
    product_version: Hyper-V UEFI Release v1.0
    system: Linux
    system_vendor: Microsoft Corporation
```

or

```yaml
    os_family: RedHat
    product_name: HVM domU
    system: Linux
    system_vendor: Xen
    virtualization_role: guest
    virtualization_type: xen
```

With this information [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) is trivial. Like in

```yaml
when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian" and ansible_facts['system_vendor'] == "Microsoft Corporation"
```

One may need only to double check the currently available or reported virtualization types.

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to detect if host is WSL in Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78046212/6771046)
- [Using `ansible_virtualization_type` returns `virtualbox` but the Remote Host is not using VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73604641/6771046)
- [Ansible Issue #66304 - "*fact `ansible_virtualization_type` incorrect for Alpine container on GitHub runner `ubuntu-latest`*"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66304)