# Using 'ansible_virtualization_type' returns 'virtualbox' but the remote host is not using VirtualBox

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have some servers running Debian 6 inside VirtualBox (host is Debian 9). From Control Node (which is also Debian 9), I ran the following to see the type of virtualization on a `node1` server which I know is not using VirtualBox.

`ansible node1 -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_virtualization_type' -i inventories/`

It's returning virtualization type as VirtualBox for `node1`.

```json
"ansible_virtualization_role": "guest"
"ansible_virtualization_type": "virtualbox"
```

I am getting false positives this way. Is there a better way to see if remote machine is running inside a VM or not?

Comment: I'm confused; it sounds like you *do* have some servers running under VirtualBox. Is `node1` one of those servers?

Comment: `node1` is  bare-metal server and ansible is returning VirtualBox as virtualization type for it.

Comment: What's the value of `ansible_virtualization_role` on that same node?

Comment: @Zeitounator `"ansible_virtualization_role": "guest"` and `"ansible_virtualization_type": "virtualbox"` on node1

Comment: From your initial description I understand that you have a Debian 9 host which is serving VirtualBox and inside that some Debian 6 VMs. A separate Debian 9 host is serving as Ansible Control Node and connecting to a bare metal server. According this it seems that the VirtualBox infrastructure is unrelated and you could remove all information about from the question. Furthermore can you provide the full output of collection [Ansible Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts)?

Comment: "According this it seems that the VirtualBox infrastructure is unrelated and you could remove all information about from the question". This information is important is it acts as a control. I can't post the full output of ansible facts. It contains sensitive information.

Comment: Means this your Ansible Control Node is a Debian 9 and running in a virtualized environment like under VirtualBox? Furthermore you could easily remove sensitive information since the data structure, keys and some values only are interesting. Your issue isn't reproducible therefore debugging details will be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question

> *Is there a better way ...*

the [`setup` module – Gathers facts about remote hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) is the recommended way to gather [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) as it

> *is automatically called by playbooks to gather useful variables about remote hosts that can be used in playbooks.*

Since the source of information is the same in almost all possible ways

> *I am getting false positives this way.*

this seems to be unlikely for me.

If you like to double check the result which is delivered from the module `setup.py` and [`facts`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts), the Python VM and [`platform.`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html), you could execute the command

```bash
dmidecode -s system-product-name
```

or after installing on Remote Nodes (Target Nodes), `virt-what`.

**Further Q&A**

- [Easy way to determine the virtualization technology of a Linux machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89718/266568)
- [Find out if the OS is running in a virtual environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127904/266568)