# How to detect if host is WSL in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, ansible-facts

In Ansible, I need to run some roles only if the host is a WSL host.

How to detect that? I am looking for a form of:

```yaml
- name: "Run only in WSL"
  when: # what to put here?
  # task definition
```

What to put in the `when` section? I am looking for a way to detect that automatically, NOT to configure a variable on my host in the inventory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just gather [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts). There is no need for `command`, `shell`, `register` and parse `stdout` at all. From a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true

  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "min"
  # - "hardware"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

the output result will already contain the requested information

```yaml
    os_family: RedHat
    product_name: VMware7,1
    system: Linux
    system_vendor: VMware, Inc.
    virtualization_role: guest
    virtualization_type: VMware
```

or

```yaml
    os_family: RedHat
    product_name: Virtual Machine
    product_version: Hyper-V UEFI Release v1.0
    system: Linux
    system_vendor: Microsoft Corporation
```

or

```yaml
    os_family: RedHat
    product_name: HVM domU
    system: Linux
    system_vendor: Xen
    virtualization_role: guest
    virtualization_type: xen
```

It also contains the `ansible_facts.kernel` versions

```yaml
3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64
4.18.0-513.11.1.el8_9.x86_64
5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64
```

With this information [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) is trivial. Like in

```yaml
when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian" and ansible_facts['system_vendor'] == "Microsoft Corporation"
```

Answer (score -1):

The command `uname -a` reports something like:

> Linux DESKTOP 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5
> 21:02:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Could be OK for what you're looking for! This was for Ubuntu 22.04 installed in WSL 2. I'm not sure how this would fit in with Ansible, but there's probably a way to make the call and filter the result for WSL2.

Comment: That sounds pretty close.  Run the shell command and register the variable.  Then use a when clause. something like: `when: "'WSL2' in variable.output"`